# Method Call Syntax in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, syntax, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm new to CoffeeScript, and I seem to be having trouble with the syntax for calling methods.

Here's the Card model:

```
class exports.Card extends Backbone.Model
  defaults:
    pip:   '4'
    suit:  '♠'
    color: 'b'

  rows: ->
    rows =
      '4': [2, 0, 2]
    rows[@pip]
```

And the relevant portion of the template:

```
<ul class="col cols-<%= @card.rows()[0] %>">
```

which is giving me the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'rows'`

Specifically, I'm wondering if I'm using incorrect syntax for the rows method of Card or if I'm just misunderstanding something. Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

For some reason, `@card.property` always works fine, but `@card.any_method()` never does. I've gotten around this at the moment by using properties, but I'd love it if someone was able to explain this behavior. Thanks again!

**Update 2:**

I'm using http://brunchwithcoffee.com if it's a help to anyone, and here's the `main.coffee` file to show how the `@card` instance is being created and passed to the view.

```
window.app = {}
app.routers = {}
app.models = {}
app.collections = {}
app.views = {}

Card = require('models/card_model').Card
MainRouter = require('routers/main_router').MainRouter
HomeView = require('views/home_view').HomeView
CardView = require('views/card_view').CardView

# app bootstrapping on document ready
$(document).ready ->
  app.initialize = ->
    app.routers.main = new MainRouter()
    app.views.home = new HomeView()
    app.views.card = new CardView(model: new Card(color: 'r', suit: '♥', pip: '7'))
    app.routers.main.navigate 'home', true if Backbone.history.getFragment() is ''
  app.initialize()
  Backbone.history.start()
```

Comment: How was `@card` created? As `new exports.Card`? Does it pass the test `@card instanceof exports.Card`?

Comment: updated to show how the @card is being created

Comment: Style tip: You can write `{Card} = require 'models/card_model'` instead of `Card = require('models/card_model').Card`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your method calling syntax is correct. The relevant rules for CoffeeScript are:

- Parenthesis are optional for method calls invoked with arguments ie

  ```
  object.method 1,2
  ```

  or

  ```
  object.method(1,2)
  ```
- Parenthesis are required for method calls invoked with no arguments ie

  ```
  object.method()
  ```

To see how this works try running the following code on the 'Try CoffeeScript' editor on the CoffeeScript site:

```
class A
  method: ->
    console.log "A"

(new A()).method();
```

Since your method call syntax is correct it seems likely that the problem is that the @card variable is not an instance of the exports.Card class.

Comment: hm, i'm really confused then--@card is definitely an instance of the Card class, as I'm able to safely to `<%= @card.pip %>` one of the previous lines in the view

Comment: you were right--@card was actually the toJSON() equivalent of what I was thinking it was

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `pip` isn't a property of the `Card` instance; it's a property of `Card::defaults`, so Backbone then makes it an *attribute* of the `Card` instance—not a *property*. You can access the `pip` attribute with

```
card.get 'pip'
```

or directly as

```
card.attributes.pip
```

The reason for this distinction is that, in JavaScript, there's no way to monitor a property for changes, which Backbone needs to do in order to dispatch events. (If you modify `pip` with `card.set 'pip'`, then Backbone fires a `"change"` event, for instance.)

So, your code should work fine if you just change the last line of the `rows` method:

```
rows: ->
  rows =
    '4': [2, 0, 2]
  rows[@get 'pip']
```

(**Note:** Getters/setters are supported in *some* JS environments, which would allow you to map `card.pip = ...` to `card.set 'pip', ...` See John Resig's article on it [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/). Backbone doesn't use this approach because it aims to be compatible with all modern-ish browsers.)

Comment: thanks for the clarification on properties versus attributes, but i'm still getting the 'has no method' error when calling any method on @card

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out--I forgot that the `@card` variable referenced in the template didn't originate from the `main.coffee` file--it was actually being converted into JSON in the `CardView` here:

```
cardTemplate = require('templates/card')

class exports.CardView extends Backbone.View
  tagName:   'div'
  className: 'card'

  render: ->
    $(@el).html cardTemplate(card: @model.toJSON())
    @
```

Now it makes sense why only variables were working and not methods -- `@card` was actually a JSON representation of the model instance.

Thanks for all the suggestions/clarifications guys--sorry for the dumb mistake :P